# Changing view controllers without the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to change views but I want have to do it through code and not through storyboard for reasons that don't really matter, and I found this code:

```
[[self ] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
```

the problem is I don't know what to put in for presentModalViewController or destinationViewController. Is there some way to figure out what my views are called so i can put them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top you should have

```
#import "NameOfViewController.h"
```

Then later

```
UIViewController *destinationViewController = [[NameOfViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Use `presentViewController` instead of `presentModalViewController` as the latter method is deprecated. I hope that works for you.

Comment: definite +1 for calling out the deprecated method

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, `[self destinationViewController]` creates and returns a UIVIewController.

You can either:

1. load one from a NIB file

   `controller = [[MyController alloc]
       initWithNibName:@"nib-resource-name" bundle:nil];`
2. load one from the storyboard

   `MyController * controller = [self.storyboard
       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller-storyboard-id"];`
3. create one programmatically

   [How do I create a UIViewController programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688659/how-do-i-create-a-uiviewcontroller-programmatically)