# How to load a xib file from another controller without segue and not as a subview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

In my project I have a :

- Main.storyboard
- a Controller "MapViewController" and his xib file
- a Controller "ViewMapViewController" and his xib file

What I'm trying to do is to call the xib file from the ViewMapViewController in the MapViewController but not as a subview, by the way is it possible?

I tried to do something like this :

```
let viewMapViewController:ViewMapViewController = ViewMapViewController()
self.presentViewController(viewMapViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And it called it but there is a dark background and I don't know why.
At first I thought that it was because of a background color but it is not, I checked it.

So there are my files :

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var gmapView: GMSMapView!
var viewMapViewController: ViewMapViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 15)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.setMinZoom(10, maxZoom: 15)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.map = mapView
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let viewMapViewController:ViewMapViewController = ViewMapViewController()
    self.presentViewController(viewMapViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here my other file :

```
class ViewMapViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should load the controllers from xib files since their outlets are all set in xib file, if you create an instance of these controller on the fly, you get an empty vew as you saw, so the correct way in swift is:

```
let vc = ViewMapViewController (nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil)
```

and you can also put your view controllers in the main storyboard, and give each of them a storyboard identifier, and load them from the storyboard:

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) as NSStoryboard
let vc= storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("YourVCIdentifier") as! NSViewController
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I don't want that much things in my storyboard because I have a lot of view that's why I use xib file.

Do you mean let vc = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("VCNibName", owner: self, options: nil)[0] ? Because my Xcode didn't recognize viewBundle

Comment: I understand, and yes if the xib file name is "ViewMapViewController", by the way you can have more than one story board in a project, and you can divide you project into several parts. And put view controllers of different part in different storyboard, and you can still use the good stuffs of storyboard like segue...

Comment: Hum ok thank you ! Otherwise I tried what you suggested :
        `let viewMapViewController = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewMapViewController", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
        self.presentViewController(viewMapViewController as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

And I have this error "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10c8dedf8) to 'UIViewController' (0x10c8e05e0)."

And if i don't cast it it doesn't build..

Comment: oh, i made a mistake, it's different to load an view or view controller from a xib, i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151026/unable-to-programatically-create-a-uiviewcontroller-in-swift/27151514#27151514), hope it'll help,

Comment: I tried it and I even tried other things but I still have this black background..

Comment: Try to put them in another storyboard and load them from the storyboard, I haven't written swift for long, so I'm not so sure about the grammar, you may look it up somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a childviewcontroller in storyboard to mapviewcontroller and assign  viewmapcontroller class to childviewcontroller. In that case you dont even have to right any code to call it, it will automatically load with mapviewcontroller.